# CSS opacity transition switch to zero immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-transitions, opacity

I cannot figure out why a composite transition (opacity and height) on the same element does not follow the expected duration. However, this issue happens only the very first time is run, then begins to work perfectly.

UPDATE:

I found a slimmer way to demonstrate the problem.

By click the "start" button, the box at the right turns immediately transparent, and does not fade slowly as the left one.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  doNative();
  doJQuery();
});

function doNative() {
  const elem = document.getElementById("bn");
  elem.style.opacity = 0;
  elem.style.height = 0;
  elem.style.transitionDuration = "2s";
  elem.style.transitionProperty = "opacity, height";
}

function doJQuery() {
  const elem = $("#bj");
  elem.css({
    opacity: 0,
    height: 0,
    "transition-duration": "2s",
    "transition-property": "opacity, height",
  });
}
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.initial {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>start</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="block">
    <div id="bn" class="initial">This box is collapsed using the native transition API</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div id="bj" class="initial">This box is collapsed using the jQuery transition API</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

LEGACY CONTENT (no relevant anymore):

Here is just a snippet to depict the context:

```
items.css({
  opacity: 0,
  height: 0,
  "transition-duration": transitionDuration + "ms",
  "transition-property": "opacity, height"
});
```

To better clarify the actual and the expected behavior, have a look at this pen: https://codepen.io/highfield/pen/dKLKKo

Once run, by pressing the "hide" button, the "Items" block disappears immediately, but the expected behavior is to fade along a certain interval.
After this initial weird phase, the "show" and "hide" functions behave perfectly as expected.

I also noticed that by removing the "height" from the "transition-property" CSS field, the opacity will fade correctly.

How to patch this problem?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question, rather than link to codepen.  That said, I suspect your problem is that you don't set the opacity of the initial state.  For example, if it is visible and you want to fade out then you need to set opacity to 1 for it to work, otherwise there's no value to transition from.  This also explains why it works after the first time.

Comment: That said, is there a reason you want to do this with Javascript, instead of using pure CSS and just adding and removing a class?

Comment: @Archer the reason to favor JS instead of stylesheets classes is for parametrization, which is easier via script. However, the "height" property seems to me a bit hard to define in a stylesheet, because it depends on the elements content.

Comment: If you just add a `show()` at the bottom of the JS it works and also gives you a nice entry animation. No idea why the first hide is not animating without this though. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYQPea

Comment: @apokryfos many thanks for the workaround, but I'd like to understand why the graphics behave so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found where the problem is.

It seems that the order of the fields matters, but I don't understand why the native version works fine, even in a random order. By changing the jQuery version as follows, the transitions behave correctly:

```
function doJQuery() {
  const elem = $("#bj");
  elem.css({
    "transition-duration": "2s",
    "transition-property": "opacity, height",
    opacity: 0,
    height: 0,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The transition properties must be set on the target element before performing any transitions. To make that initial animation work too, you should set a basic transition definition to the `#s1` element in CSS.

Comment: I've just noticed that the problem appears only with jQuery 3.x. By using jQuery 2.x there's no problem at all.

Comment: Anyway, if you take a look at the script, you'll notice an initial CSS settings followed by a short delay.

Comment: @MarioVernari Your problem is a misunderstanding of how CSS transitions work – this is independent of any JS libraries.

Comment: I may accept your critics, but you should show me where I'm wrong. Have a look at the pen: where is my mistake? Again, how is that by using JQuery 2.x the problem disappears?

Comment: If you have just a minute to see the simplified demo above, as well as my answer among those, you'll understand that the problem is beyond your (even correct) consideration.